# What's good for the goose is good for the gander

Tags: meaning, idiom-requests

Looking for an alternative way to say "what's good for the goose is good for the gander

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE! I advise taking the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site works. The goal of this site is to provide detailed answers to questions about English. Because of this, questions are expected to provide detail and context to make it easier for other users to write good answers. Please edit your question to explain why you are looking for an alternative expression, and specify as much as you can what type of expression you do want.

Comment: It may help to look over the [question checklist for single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info); I know you are requesting an expression rather than a single word, but I think the advice there is mostly applicable to this kind of question as well.

Comment: I've heard this as "What's sauce for the goose...."

Comment: That's the proverb. _Sauce for the goose is sauce for the gander_. I.e, treat male and female alike, neither one has special privilege or special restriction.

Answer (score 3):

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what%27s_good_for_the_goose_is_good_for_the_gander) offers a clear restatement of this idiom:

> What is good for a woman is equally good for a man.

This phrasing preserves the gender implied in the original idiom (gander is male, goose is female). If you want to say it without referring to gender, use:

> What is good for one is equally good for all.